# Merge two dataframes by a partial match in R

Tags: r

I want to merge two data frames by name; however, the names differ slightly between the two data frames. Is there a way to merge these two data frames by a partial match? I have tried answers to other posts but have not gotten the results I need. Thanks

```r
#Create data frames
df1 <- data.frame(
  "Attending" = c("Kokabi, Nima", "Tong, Frank Charles","Devireddy, Chandan",
                  "Greenbaum, Adam B","Amin, Dina"),
  "Outcome" = rep(1, times = 5),stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(
  "Credentialed" = c("Kokabi, Nima, MD","Tong, Frank Charles, MD",
                     "Devireddy, Chandanreddy M, MD", "Greenbaum, Adam Brett, MD",
                     "Amin, Dina, DDS"),
  "Status" = rep("Active", times = 5),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
#Desired result
final <- data.frame(
  "Attending" = c("Kokabi, Nima", "Tong, Frank Charles","Devireddy, 
Chandan","Greenbaum, Adam B","Amin, Dina"),
  "Outcome" = rep(1, times = 5),
  "Credentialed" = c("Kokabi, Nima, MD","Tong, Frank Charles, 
MD","Devireddy, Chandanreddy M, MD", "Greenbaum, Adam Brett, MD","Amin, 
Dina, DDS"),
  "Status" = rep("Active", times = 5)
)

head(final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `grep`.

```r
df1$Credentialed <- grep(paste(df1$Attending,collapse = '|'),df2$Credentialed,value=T)

left_join(df1,df2)

Joining, by = "Credentialed"
            Attending Outcome                  Credentialed Status
1        Kokabi, Nima       1              Kokabi, Nima, MD Active
2 Tong, Frank Charles       1       Tong, Frank Charles, MD Active
3  Devireddy, Chandan       1 Devireddy, Chandanreddy M, MD Active
4   Greenbaum, Adam B       1     Greenbaum, Adam Brett, MD Active
5          Amin, Dina       1               Amin, Dina, DDS Active
```

Note, I would suggest setting `stringsAsFactors=F` in your data.frame call. And note how you pasted the names -- the return will be read by R, not as a space.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  "Attending" = c("Kokabi, Nima", "Tong, Frank Charles","Devireddy, Chandan",
                  "Greenbaum, Adam B","Amin, Dina"),
  "Outcome" = rep(1, times = 5),stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(
  "Credentialed" = c("Kokabi, Nima, MD","Tong, Frank Charles, MD",
                     "Devireddy, Chandanreddy M, MD", "Greenbaum, Adam Brett, MD",
                     "Amin, Dina, DDS"),
  "Status" = rep("Active", times = 5),stringsAsFactors = F)
```